# White bars above and below text in header

Tags: html, css

Probably I am missing something fundamental, but here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cqn5g94r/5/

```css
html {
  background: black;
}

.header {
  font-size: 6vh;
  color: rgb(245, 246, 230);
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #45adc1, #64f1c2);
  /* DELETE THE BORDER*/
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="header">
  <p>My Title</p>
</div>
```

If you delete the border, you can see, that the whole thing shrinks. And I want it to be thinner, but without the emty space above and below. Some Help anyone?

Comment: margin-collapsing of `p` .. add `p {margin:0}`

Comment: @dippas, i don't agree with this duplicate. It's not only an issue with the margin of body but margin-collpasing issue. The p tag has margin going outside the header and when he add border the margin is inside. So he doesn't understand this behavior. So yes he has to make margin of body 0 and also understand the margin-collapsing and add margin:0 to p also [the link i shared]

Comment: `p, body { margin: 0 }`